# htaccess how to redirect both www.domain.com AND domain.com to www.realdomain.com

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have an htaccess redirect set up for a bunch of domains to all point towards my main domain - however they only redirect `domain.com` to `www.realdomain.com`, if you hit `www.domain.com` the redirect doesn't take place.

Here's what I have (rewritecond and rewriterules are replicated for each domain):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.realdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My knowledge of regexp is a bit limited but I gather that it looks for an address BEGINNING with `domain.com`, so it makes sense it wouldn't match `www.domain.com`.

Is there a way I can make that regexp match both of them without having to double the number of rules I already have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have it optionally also match `www.` by changing the line to `rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?domain.com [nc]`